# Easy command sequence to git-lfs upload without cloning

Tags: git-lfs

I have a zip file `myBig.zip` at a machine without a `git clone` repo, but the remote git  was prepared as an [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/), and is operating with no problem.

Puting in other words: need to do upload like in an old FTP by `put myBig.zip` command, put into the server-side  (git) repository, and only it... By easyest (default) way.

Comment: Hum... No chance? See [git-lfs/issues/2521](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2521#issuecomment-324483693).